# Does the MCU version of Mjolnir carry the "Whosoever holds this hammer..." inscription?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, thor-2011

Related to this question: [If Mjolnir was made for Thor, why is Hela seen using it in Thor: Ragnarok before it was even given to him?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/174123/if-mjolnir-was-made-for-thor-why-is-hela-seen-using-it-in-thor-ragnarok-before)

Is there any evidence that the MCU version of the hammer bears the famous inscription? Clearly we see the enchantment being placed, but are the words physically inscribed on the weapon? Part of my answer to the other question posits that it doesn't, but due to a comment on that answer, I'm not so sure.

I've seen images of a number of replicas that show it, but is there any *on-screen* evidence, either in the original film or in Thor's other appearances in the MCU?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### No

There are a bunch of Nordic symbols on the edges, and the special symbol that appears when Odin enchants it.

[image]

This symbol appears only a few times, both faces of the hammer are normally blank.

[image]

When Vision lifts the hammer in Avengers: Age of Ultron. You see both sides of it.

Neither does the bottom contain any writing.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

**It does not.**

When Odin places the enchantment on it, this [triquetra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triquetra) symbol appears briefly.

[image]

The other side is blank

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! No idea why I couldn't locate that second picture when I was searching.

Comment: Anyone else think these screens are too dark to see what's on the hammer?

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Try angling your monitor down slightly.

Comment: I had to turn my brightness up to max. Maybe it's time to get a new screen. :)

Comment: @DCOPTimDowd - Or better eyes?

Comment: I already have four. I can't afford two **new** ones.

Comment: Four screens? Or four eyes?